# Single Kanji alters when pasted from Illustrator to VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste, adobe-illustrator

I am encountering an unusual issue while working with Japanese Kanji characters. I use Adobe Illustrator for some of my tasks, and often need to copy text from Illustrator and paste it into Visual Studio Code. I'm using a Mac.

The problem is that occasionally, a single Kanji character changes upon pasting into VS Code. Most of the time, everything works fine, and all characters are copied and pasted correctly. However, every once in a while, one character in the pasted text will be different from the original character in Illustrator. The character that changes seems to be random, and there's no clear pattern to when this happens.

For examples, in some instances, the character '検' becomes '檢', '削' becomes '消', and '要' becomes '票'. While these characters look somewhat similar, they carry different meanings.

Here are some points to consider:

The issue is not consistent. It happens occasionally.
Only one character changes, the rest of the text remains the same.
The issue is not related to displaying the characters in VS Code, as they generally display correctly.
Copying the text to another text editor does not replicate the issue.
I've ruled out encoding issues as all characters usually display correctly. I've also considered clipboard issues, but I'm unsure how to proceed with this.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem or could provide some insight into what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Hello, showing examples of the characters that cause this would help you get an answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  Sure, I can provide some examples. In some instances, the character '検' becomes '檢', '削' becomes '消', and '要' becomes '票'. While these characters look somewhat similar, they carry different meanings.

Comment: Add any extra info to the question, not only comments.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Do you have something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GlenBuktenica.unicode-substitutions in VSCode doing unicode substitution? I wouldn't expect it to operate on Kanji, but maybe it has a bug? Those characters are not even close in the unicode character set https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+6AA2 and https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+691C

Comment: I checked in my VSCode and no substitutions were ever made within like 30 attempts in bunch of different files. Does it happen to you with some specific files or all? DId you try temporarily resetting settings to default ones? Which extensions do you use?